# Acumatica / Myob Advanced: add an email field

Tags: email, acumatica

On Myob Advanced (Acumatica), we would like to add a salespersons email address to the Salespersons page (AR205000). This is so that we can then add this field to the Sales Order email template, allowing us to CC the salesperson in every time their customer places an order.

Ive tried to implement this extra field, "Salespersons Email Address"; but I am having some issues.

1. It will only allow me to save 25 characters within the text box? How come I'm unable to add more than 25 characters?
2. Email fields that come with the software all have the code of px:PXMailEdit. However, i cant seem to be able to create a MailEdit field, only a px:PXTextEdit field? Why is this?

Thanks for your help. If this doesnt make sense or you need further info LMK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Layout Editor does not support *PXMailEdit* control. Please find below the steps to add a custom email field on the **Salespersons** screen:

1. For the **SalesPerson** DAC, ceate a new field of the string type with length set to 255 (this is the length defined in the `PXDBEmailAttribute` used on all email fields in Acumatica/MYOB Advanced):
   [image]
   [image]
2. Replace generated attributes with the attributes below, save your changes and publish customization:

   ```
   [PXDBEmail]
   [PXUIField(DisplayName="Email Address")]
   ```

   [image]
3. Open the **Salespersons** screen in Layout Editor and add *TextEdit* control for the custom field declared on step 1, then save your changes:
   [image]
4. Select **Edit Project Items** from the **File** menu and change control type from `PX.Web.UI.PXTextEdit` to `PX.Web.UI.PXMailEdit` in the XML changeset generated for the Salespersons screen, save your changes and publish customization one more time:
   [image]

This is how custom email field should look like on the Salespersons screen after you complete the steps above:
[image]

**Using Salesperson's email in Automation Notifications:**

If you set up custom Email Address field from the Salespersons screen as CC address in Sales Order notification:
[image]
the system will automatically include Email Address from the Default Salesperson in notification message:
[image]
[image]

**Using Salesperson's email in Notification Templates:**

This might seem a litle confusing, but the Sales Person node available for selection on the Notification Templates screen represents an Employee linked with a Salesperson (see screenshot below for details):
[image]

With SalesOrderNotification's CC field set to `((SalesPerson.SalesPersonID.UsrEmailAddress))`, the system should automatically include Email Address from the Default Salesperson in the generated email:

[image]

Comment: Thanks heaps for this information, its great! Ive now installed the field. However, theres just one issue - the new field is fine, and it shows up as an option on the SalesOrderNotification email template. Ive set it to automatically fill in the CC line on the email template, but it always comes up empty when we're actually emailing out the sales notifications. Why is that? Love some help if anyone knows as to this.

Comment: Could you please compare your notification template configuration with one from my updated answer above (the **Using Salesperson's email in Automation Notifications** section)

Comment: I was doing this SalesOrderNotification template from the Notification Templates SM204003 page (Configuration>Email>Notification Templates). This is where our Sales Orders emails are currently getting their template from. I was adding the Salespersons Email Address to the CC field here. Should I be doing all this from the Automatic Notifications SM205040 page?

Comment: Notification Templates and Automation Notifications are meant for different purposes. It's very hard, if even possible, to suggest using one over another. Could you please compare your SalesOrderNotification notification template configuration with one from my updated answer above (the **Using Salesperson's email in Notification Templates** section)

Comment: The salesperson field on the Employees (EP203000) page were all empty. I have filled them in, and the salespersons email now automatically enters into Sales Orders emails! However sorry this results in another issue - not all of our salespeople are employees. Some salespeople are commission salespeople, and work independently from the company. Is there any way to get these salespersons email to automatically prefill as well?

Comment: I think this goes well beyond the original question and has to be in a separate thread...